# "meta user" link doesn't work for all users

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, profile-page, per-site-meta

Just noticed the "meta user" link under the picture and reputation on the Stack Exchange user's page. It doesn't seem to work for all users. Error is "Page Not Found".

1. Not working: [SPSE user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1066/sam) / [Meta SPSE user](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1066)
2. Working: [SPSE user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/31/alex-angas) / [Meta SPSE user](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31)

My guess is this is because they've never logged into the meta site.

Comment: This is true. A meta user account is *not* created until user actually visits the meta site.

Comment: the link shouldn't appear unless the user has a meta account, and you won't unless you have actively visited meta

Comment: @JeffAtwood and yet _that_ user has such a link.

Comment: @jcolebrand Yep, that's why this meta post exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed, we fetch a list of which users exist on the meta every 5 minutes, if they're on the list they get a link on their profile.